# Какое основное преимущество кортежа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, что основное преимущество кортежа перед списком заключается в размере и скорости доступа?

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python3

q = (1,2,3)
w = [1,2,3]

print(q.__sizeof__())  # 48
print(w.__sizeof__())  # 64
```

Остальные отличия типа возможности использовать кортеж в виде ключа для словаря довольно экзотические и применяются редко

Comment: ну, еще кортеж неизменяемый.. такого рода защита "от дурака" и возможности выстрелов в собственную ногу.

Comment: Не совсем. Если элементы кортежа изменяемые, то в них можно внести изменения)

Comment: Полезна статья
[Хабр][1]


  [1]: https://habr.com/ru/post/417783/

Comment: @rettoryh13, ну а ссылки то останутся неизменными. Если приводить аналогию из C++, то это будет константный указатель.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что использование кортежа в качестве ключа словаря или элемента множества - это что-то экзотическое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Размер
2. Скорость
3. Неизменяемость
4. Кортеж можно использовать в качестве ключа словаря из-за неизменяемости
5. Различные разрешённые операции

   `aaa=(1,2)
   aaa[0]=0 # TypeError
   bbb=[1,2]
   bbb[0]=2 
   bbb # [2,2]`
6. Кортеж хешируемый объект, а список - нет

   `hash(aaa) # 1278979879
   hash(bbb) # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
7. Защита от дурака
8. Использование там где одно значение не имеет смысла без другого

Comment: Можно еще добавить туда namedtuple :)

Comment: @nick_gabpe я правильно понимаю, что пункты 2 и 6 связаны?

Comment: @rettoryh13 нет. Это всё из-за неизменямости. Как я понимаю: кортеж создаётся один раз и создаётся как константа. Потом он просто "подглядывает" значение этой константы где-то у себя внутри в таблице констант. Список же создаётся, но потом он может изменяться и интерпретатору нужно каждый раз смотреть 1) сколько элементов у списка и 2) чему равно их значение прямо сейчас, а это занимает некоторое время. 

Но это как я понимаю, а я могу ошибаться.

Comment: @gil9red можно, я читал про него, но сам не сталкивался, поэтому могу написать глупость :)